# Retrieving ToggleGroup name JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to retrieve the "name" (or any type of unique identifier) of the ToggleGroup of a given ToggleButton, and have been having no success. It is important, if possible, that the different buttons share the event handler. Any help?

```
//create toggleGroups
final ToggleGroup toggleGroup1 = new ToggleGroup();
final ToggleGroup toggleGroup2 = new ToggleGroup();

//create toggleButtons
final ToggleButton toggleButton1 = new ToggleButton("b1");
final ToggleButton toggleButton2 = new ToggleButton("b2");

//assign toggleButtons to toggleGroups
toggleButton1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup1);
toggleButton2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup2);

//assign custom handler to toggleButtons
toggleButton1.setOnAction(new handleEvent());
toggleButton2.setOnAction(new handleEvent());

//handler
class handleEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

        // enable ability to get toggleButton name later
        ToggleButton b = (ToggleButton)e.getSource();

        //get name of group toggleButton belongs too?
        String toggleGroup = b.getToggleGroup().toString();

        // do stuff based on name and group
        if (toggleGroup == "toggleGroup1") {
            //do stuff
        } else if (toggleGroup == "toggleGroup2") {
            //d other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add event handlers separately to each button? `#setOnAction` is the function you are looking for. You won't need to remember toggle groups then.

Comment: You can set the name as userData: `toggleGroup.setUserData("toggleGroupName")`. To retrieve it back you call: `String name = (String) toggleGroup.getUserData()`

Comment: @jns could you submit that as an answer so I can mark it? Worked perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the name as userData: `toggleGroup.setUserData("toggleGroupName")`

To retrieve it back you call: `String name = (String) toggleGroup.getUserData()`